# Trigger for a visual force page which has controller

Tags: visualforce, trigger, controller

Can I write an trigger for a visual force page which has controller? I have a Visualforce page created on Opportunity object which is in PDF format. I have a few RollUp summary fields created on opportunity object. There is a Wrapper class written on Opportunity Product. Now I would like to call these RollUp summary fields in the wrapper class based on a Condition. How do I call the RollUp summary field in a trigger? Any help very much appreciated.

Subtotal__c ,Pick_Total__cand Non_Pick_Total__c are Roll up summary fields on Opportunity Object. They give the "Sum" of Opportunity Product aggregates on Extension Field.

Extension(Extension=qty*1) is a Formula field data type as Currency on Opportunity Product.

Based on the requirement 1:

1)I need write custom calculation for the roll up summary field in a controller.  and opportunityline items as well as formula field (Extension=qty*1).

Requriement2:

2)Can I write a trigger on the Formula field (i.e . Extension) by calling the roll up summary fields (subtotatl,Nonpicktotal,picktotal).?

Comment: You might need to be a little more clear on what you are asking.  After reading that, I'm still not really sure what you want.  You don't write triggers for Visualforce pages.  They are for specific objects.

Comment: Your ask as written does not fit at all with Salesforce architecture. Please outline your question in a format more like: "I am trying to do X, but struggling because of Y." For example X might be calculating a formula on a VisualForce Page. [Triggers](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm) are centered around database operations, which you are not really performing in this context.

Comment: @ Adrian Larson:I have updated the query.